# Creating FTP Accounts with Rails + S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Is there a way to crate a ftp account to a specific folder inside a bucket in s3 with rails?

I need users to upload files via ftp to a batch folder. Since files are both big in size and large in quantities i guess the best choice is via FTP and avoid all web uploading.

Let's say i have a User model with a role collaborator. When is a collaborator he can log with his username (user1) / password on let's say ftp.mysite.com and go to

s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/batches/users/user1

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the users interacts with FTP and not with a web app, you can implement a plain Ruby script instead of a Rails web application.

- Every user has own FTP area to upload files to; `ftp.mysite.com/user1`, `ftp.mysite.com/user2`, ...
- Periodically a script checks if there is any new file in users' FTP folder using `net/ftp` standard library
- If there is any, uploads the file so S3 via [AWS::S3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/), eventually creating the folder on the S3 bucket if its missing
- Once uploaded to S3, the file is deleted from FTP

Notes:

1. Every user should access only to own FTP folder, while the Ruby script should access to any FTP folder
2. If your users can use FTP, they can probably use [Amazon S3 Organizer(S3Fox)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3247/), [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) or other S3 client. Create a bucket, users and folders then play with S3 ACL to define their privileges.